# Puzzled by Apache RewriteEngine

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, url-rewriting

My webroot is `example.com`.  I have two sub-directories below webroot, named `sub1` and `sub2`.  Inside `sub1`I've placed the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test\.me$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/sub2/foo.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub2/foo.html [L]
```

When someone tries to access `http://example.com/sub1/test.me`, I want them to be served `http://example.com/sub2/foo.html`.

The above `.htaccess` does not work.  If I un-comment the RewriteRule with the full path, and comment out the RewriteRule with the path relative to the webroot, it almost works as intended (the right page is shown, but the URL shown is also changed from  `http://example.com/sub1/test.me` to `http://example.com/sub2/foo.html`, which is not wanted).

I am not able to understand why the full path almost works, while the path relative to the siteroot don't.

And if anyone could explain why my approach don't work, and what the the "best practice" for doing this type of redirection is - I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.

Unfortunately, I oversimplified the setting when I composed the question.  In fact, in a "virgin" environment the original `.htaccess` works exactly as I intended it to work.

However, the setting I'm using this `.htaccess` is with Drupal 7, and this makes a difference, since Drupal 7 uses "clean URLs".

What I found is that rewriting to a "clean" url do not work.  So the following rule in `.htaccess` do not work when redirecting to Drupal node #1:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub2/node/1
```

However, the following does:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub2/?q=node/1
```

Apologies for not putting all that was relevant for cracking it in the question.
I hope this answer helps someone that struggles with the same thing.